# Python unittest call function when assertion fails

Tags: python, unit-testing

**Aim:** I need to call a bunch of steps (hence a function) only if a test fails.

**What I tried:**

1) Tried passing function w/o arguments.

**Observation :** If test passes, function doesn't get called. But if test fails, I get an error. `(AssertionError: <bound method TestAuto.func1 of <test_fail.TestAuto testMethod=test_fail>>)`

```
class TestAuto(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_fail(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1, self.func1)
    def func1(self):
        print 'We are inside'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**:**

```
test_fail (test_fail.TestAuto) ... ok

----------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

2) Tried calling function with arguments.

```
class TestAuto(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_fail(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1, self.func1('message'))
    def func1(self, msg):
        print msg
```

**Observation :** Function gets called no matter test passes or fails.

**Result:**

test_fail (test_fail.TestAuto) ... message
ok

---

Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK

Comment: It wont because there is no reason for 1 is equals to 1 `assertEqual(first, second, msg="message!")` the third parameter is message. And there is more: in first one you doesnt call the function with ->()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ordinal `try/except` statement:

```
from exceptions import AssertionError as AE

class TestAuto(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_not_fail(self):
        # won't call func1
        try:
            self.assertEqual(1, 1)
        except AE:
            self.func1()
            raise

    def test_fail(self):
        # will call func1
        try:
            self.assertEqual(1, 9)
        except AE:
            self.func1()
            raise

    def func1(self):
        print 'We are inside'
```

It can be implemented as a decorator for convenient usage:

```
from exceptions import AssertionError as AE

def run_if_test_fails(call_on_fail):
    def deco(f):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                f(*args, **kwargs)
            except AE:
                # test failed - run callback
                call_on_fail()
                # reraise Error to mark it in result
                raise
        return inner
    return deco

def func1():
    print('We are inside')

class TestAuto(unittest.TestCase):

    @run_if_test_fails(func1)
    def test_not_fail(self):
        # won't call func1
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

    @run_if_test_fails(func1)
    def test_fail(self):
        # will call func1
        self.assertEqual(1, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "message" argument to the various assert Methods is intended as a string to describe the test failure. In your first example you pass a function. If the assert succeeds it's not used, if the test fails it's printed (because that's what happens to the message).

In your second example you've made a function call in order to prepare the argument - this happens *before* assertEquals is called. 'message' is printed because of your call to print in func1.

Comment: I agree on you point. That explains the behavior observed. I although found a solution to my problem (Posted here). Tell me if you agree.

Answer (score 0):

The msg=None expects something to display. So if we want to use a function, we need to return it something. Now i have tried with string only and it works.

```
class TestAuto(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_fail(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1, msg=self.func1('2 msg'))
    def func1(self, mesg=None):
        if mesg:
            return mesg
        else:
            return 'Just an error'
```

1) Case 1: When test fails

```
==============================================================
FAIL: test_fail (test_fail.TestAuto)
--------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_fail.py", line 5, in test_fail
    self.assertEqual(1, 2, msg=self.func1('2 msg'))
AssertionError: 2 msg

--------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

2) Case 2: When test passes

```
self.assertEqual(1, 1, msg=self.func1('2 msg'))

test_fail (test_fail.TestAuto) ... ok

--------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: `self.func1('2 msg')` will be called despite on whether test fails or not

Comment: @GennadyKandaurov..You are right . I just found that out. I am trying to catch the status of the test and use it inside that called function.